# Can't update: no tracked branch error :pathspec 'mybranch' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I want to update me android studio project to github
but it said

```
Can't Update  
                    No tracked branch configured for branch origin or the branch doesn't exist.  
                    To make your branch track a remote branch call,  for example,
                    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/origin origin (show balloon)
```

I have try the method

```
git checkout mybranch  
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/mybranch
```

but it said

```
'error :pathspec 'mybranch' did not match any file(s) known to git'
```

I am not sure what to do at this point. Is there a way to fix this from within Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$ git remote update
$ git fetch
```

List all the branches using:

```
$ git branch
```

If the branch exists, you can checkout to that branch using

```
$ git checkout mybranch
```

Comment: at '$ git checkout --track origin/mybranch' it came out 'fatal: 'origin/mybranch' is not a commit and a branch 'mybranch' can not be created from it'

Comment: So you want to add new commits to an existing branch? Did you clone the repository or is this a new repository? Can you try out the above steps. Once you get to that branch, we'll update it.

Comment: What was the issue?